# Graphing software for best fit curve

Tags: data-visualization, graphs, data-analysis

I am looking for a specific graphing software that can take in values for X axis and Y axis and then output a best fit curve.

By using Excel 2010, I am able to output this nice curve:

[image: example graph 1]

However, I want the points to be connected by a curve like this:

[image: example graph 2]

Are there any graphing softwares out there, free or paid (as long as they have free trial or free demo), that will allow me to get a best fit curve like in the 2nd picture not like the 1st one without manually inputting the equation to plot the curve?

I have tried using Graph 4.4.2, Geogebra, Graphical Analysis and TI-Nspire student software but I couldn't quite get the curve I want. Maybe I am not doing the right way?

Comment: If you have a MATLAB licence you can do it easily with the built-in function `interp1` (http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). You can choose the properties of the lines to get the best result.

Comment: Hmmm... those are two different curves that can both approximate the same data set (given the data points provided).  However, given the first data point, the first curve is more accurate.  No matter the application, you'll have to provide the application with more data or parameters to generate the second curve.

Answer (score 2):

The software that I've used in the past to come up with best-fit curves is LoggerPro by Vernier. It's really powerful and has many different options. It should be able to calculate an equation of the best fit curve (if you give me the data, I can try it now). LoggerPro does have a [demo here](http://www.vernier.com/downloads/logger-pro-demo/) along with a lite version, [Logger Lite](http://www.vernier.com/products/software/logger-lite/#download).

> ## Logger Pro (commercial w/ demo)
>
> - Auto-ID sensors make setup effortless.
> - Collect live data from more than 80 different sensors and devices.
> - Draw predictions on a graph before collecting data.
> - Use a variety of data-collection modes, as needed, for your experiment: time-based data, selected events, events with typed-in entries, photogate, radiation counting, and more.
> - Manually enter data for graphing and analysis.
> - Import data from Vernier interfaces.
> - Layout graphs, tables, and text as needed across multiple pages to describe your experiment.
> - Read values and slope from graphs using examine and tangent line tools.
> - Print graphs and data tables.
>
> [image: Logger Pro GUI]

Answer (score 0):

You could "pre process" your data prior to graphing.

From the looks of it you want to plot a +/- sine wave decay-curve from the data for the sine wave.

It is relatively straight forward - using > and < functions to allocate a "zero value" and allocate each value as +ve or -ve from that...you can then invert the -ve values by means of a simple modulus function which would then plot the data in the way you are seeking...no additional software required.
Hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).